# Bootstrap 3 - some images resize, other don't

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and, as you see in the code, i have two images. Both of them have the ".img-responsive" class so i don't know why only the first one is resizing and the second one is always the same size.

**HTML :**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <img src="img/ea.png" class="img-responsive" id="img-center" width="700" height="229">
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 frase">
            <p>LOREM IPSUM</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="img/arrow.PNG" class="img-responsive" style="margin:0 auto;" width="80px" height="65px">
    </a>
</div>
```

In case you're wondering, the id "img-center" only has "margin:0 auto" and "margin-bottom:45vh;

Comment: The 2nd image has a inline style which will override the bootstrap responsive styles. You may use an extra class for this image and use `!important` to override inline style. Or if it's possible remove the inline styles.

Answer (score 2):

When you apply the `width` and `height` attributes to an element, it will override the `width: 100%` setting of `.img-responsive`.

However, the reason that the first image is responsive and the second is not, you did not append `px` to the end of the sizes for the first image. The browser would not know how to interpret that, so it would revert to the original `width: 100%;` setting.

```
<img ... class="img-responsive" ... width="700" height="229">
<img ... class="img-responsive" ... width="80px" height="65px">
```

To make both images responsive, you have to remove the fixed sizing attributes.

```
<img src="img/ea.png" class="img-responsive" id="img-center">
<img src="img/arrow.PNG" class="img-responsive" style="margin:0 auto;">
```

Answer (score 0):

That because you're using different inline-style `width` and `height` in the both of them, so try to remove the inline style because is prevent the class `img-responsive` to be applicable.

**First img :**

```
<img src="http://img.freepik.com/free-photo/background-with-white-squares-free-vector_23
-2147501484.jpg?size=338c&ext=jpg" class="img-responsive" id="img-center">
```

**Second img :**

```
<img src="http://img.freepik.com/free-photo/background-with-white-squares-free-vector_23
-2147501484.jpg?size=338c&ext=jpg" class="img-responsive" style="margin:0 auto;" >
```

Hope this help. Take a look at 
**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10434/)**.